# Python scatter plot is not shown, only the scales are updated

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to use the same structure of another simpler code to create a live-updating plot in python.

This is the simple one that works perfectly, updating the same figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

# Create initial data
x = [15.1, 15.1, 15.1, 15.1, 15.1, 15.1, 15.1]
y =[10.3, 10.8, 11.3, 11.8, 12.3, 12.8, 13.3]
values = [31.628036009300377, 32.7041794935823, 32.41961219746959, 32.2074371367232, 32.69759838127627, 33.06824662635184, 32.44804260263164]  # Array of values for the colormap

plt.ion()  # Turn on interactive mode
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, c=values, cmap='viridis', vmin=0, vmax=1)
ax.set_title("Dynamic Scatter Plot")

# Simulate continuous data updates in a loop
while True:
    # Generate new random data and values
    x = np.random.rand(50)
    y = np.random.rand(50)
    values = np.random.rand(50)

    # Update the scatter plot data and colors
    scatter.set_offsets(np.column_stack((x, y)))
    scatter.set_array(values)

    # Redraw the updated plot
    fig.canvas.draw()

    # Pause for a short duration to make the update visible
    plt.pause(0.1)

# Optionally, turn off interactive mode when you're done
plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

And this is my code that doesnt show the dots in the figure. Althogh, if I uncomment the 4 lines in the while loop, then the dots are shown but it creates another figure at each while cycle.

```
import time, os,my_module
from my_module import getData,init_list_of_objects, plot
from statistics  import mean, stdev
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

global DATA
j=0
size=400 #(autodefine it using list dir somehow)

filename,x,y,z,labels,date=[],[],[],[],[],[]
average, deviation=[],[]

folder_path = "data"  # Relative folder path
  
def Statistics(data): #given an array with data, it does the maths for average and deviation
    average.append(mean(data))
    deviation.append(stdev(data))
    #print('\nAverage and deviation calculated.')

signal= init_list_of_objects(size) #defines a matrix for the signal 'cuz each file has an array of data--> I need a matrix for all the files
DATA=dict(filename=filename,x=x,y=y,signal=signal,labels=labels, date=date) #dictionary with all the data and info related to the excel files

seen_files = set()

plt.ion()  # Turn on interactive mode
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap='cool')
ax.set_title("Dynamic Scatter Plot")
# Create a color bar
cbar = fig.colorbar(scatter, ax=ax)

while True:
    new_files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith('.xls') and f not in seen_files]
    for new_file in new_files:
        print(f"\n------------------------\nNew file added: {new_file},\n\t getting data...")
        getData(folder_path,new_file,DATA,j) 
        Statistics(DATA['signal'][j])
        
        x,y,z=plot(DATA,average)
        
        # Update the scatter plot data and colors
        scatter.set_offsets(np.column_stack((x, y)))
        scatter.set_array(z)

        # Update the color bar limits
        scatter.set_clim(vmin=min(z), vmax=max(z))

        # Redraw the updated plot
        fig.canvas.draw()
        fig.canvas.flush_events() 

        # Pause for a short duration to make the update visible
        plt.pause(1)
        
        '''fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap='cool')
        ax.set_title("Dynamic Scatter Plot")
        cbar = fig.colorbar(scatter, ax=ax)'''

           
        seen_files.add(new_file)
        j+=1
    time.sleep(10)  # Check every 10 seconds (adjust as needed)

plt.show()
```

Why the same logic fails in my case?

I also tried to place in different parts of the code `plt.show()` or `plt.clf`, however nothing changed.
The arrays x, y and z are being filled by the while-loop and if I uncomment those 4 lines I get the plot correctly at each while-cycle. I just can't figure out why i cant update the first one.

Comment: Your `while` loops are infinite -- they never end.  Thus, you never run `plt.show()`.

Comment: I thought so, and I tried to put it inside. However, it doesn't work and, anyway, it wouldn't explain why I can see the plot if I uncomment those 4 lines inside the loop even though the 'plt.show()' is kept outside the while.
Besides, the simpler code follows the same structure and works :/

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the bug.

Here's the code:

```
import time, os,my_module
from my_module import getData,init_list_of_objects, plot
from statistics  import mean, stdev
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

global DATA
j=0
size=400 #(autodefine it using list dir somehow)

filename,x,y,z,labels,date=[],[],[],[],[],[]
average, deviation=[],[]

folder_path = "data"  # Relative folder path
  
def Statistics(data): #given an array with data, it does the maths for average and deviation
    average.append(mean(data))
    deviation.append(stdev(data))
    #print('\nAverage and deviation calculated.')

signal= init_list_of_objects(size) #defines a matrix for the signal 'cuz each file has an array of data--> I need a matrix for all the files
DATA=dict(filename=filename,x=x,y=y,signal=signal,labels=labels, date=date) #dictionary with all the data and info related to the excel files


seen_files = set()


plt.ion()  # Turn on interactive mode
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap='cool')
ax.set_title("Dynamic Scatter Plot")
ax.set_ylabel('y (mm)')
ax.set_xlabel('x (mm)')

# Create a color bar
cbar = fig.colorbar(scatter, ax=ax)


while True:
    new_files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith('.xls') and f not in seen_files]
    for new_file in new_files:
        print(f"\n------------------------\nNew file added: {new_file},\n\t getting data...")
        getData(folder_path,new_file,DATA,j) 
        Statistics(DATA['signal'][j])
        
        x,y,z=plot(DATA,average)
        
        # Update the color bar limits
        scatter.set_clim(vmin=min(z), vmax=max(z))

        # Redraw the updated plot
        fig.canvas.draw()
        fig.canvas.flush_events() 
        # Update the scatter plot data and colors
        scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap='cool')
   
        # Pause for a short duration to make the update visible
        plt.pause(1)
        plt.show()

        
        seen_files.add(new_file)
        j+=1
    time.sleep(10)  # Check every 10 seconds (adjust as needed)
```

It's slightly different, but essentially it is the same code. My issue was with the editor that I was using (Spyder) that, for some reason, was not working properly. I ran the code with a simple python IDLE and the bug was gone!

I hope it will help someone!